# Token MisMatch Exception when send form data from angular 2 to laravel

Tags: laravel, token, angular2-services

How to send csrf token from angular 2 post request to laravel post route. Weather it should be send in header or with form data. Any guidance will be highly appreciated..

Comment: it usually goes with the form. I'd suggest using csrf_field()

Answer (score 0):

you have two options either add an input field and send it like this. p.s not sure if you can do it in angular. like this:

```
angular.module("app").constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>');
```

or for testing purposes just go to `app/http/middleware/verifycsrftoken` and set the routes that you want to exclude from the token verify :

```
  protected $except = [
            'api/*'
        ];
```